# jquery focusout event fires in ie not firefox

Tags: jquery

I am using the following in my ASP.Net/ajax update panel page's pageload

```
$('#Mydiv').focusout(function (event) {
...
});
```

It seems my event never gets fired. I can step through the pageload with firebug and see that this line gets execute but it never fires.

Also in that function I am using:
event.toElement
event.target

Do you know if those have cross-browser support or if there is a correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Try using onblur instead. (It doesn't bubble up, though.)

http://help.dottoro.com/ljmusasd.php

Comment: But then event.target is null. How can I get the element that to which the user is trying to set the focus?

Comment: Oh, I found it document.activeElement. But the problem with blur is that new target receives focus.

Answer (score -1):

The correct code should be

```
$('#Mydiv').blur(function (event) {
...
});
```